# How do make grails datePicker '0000-00-00 00:00:00' by default, instead of inserting blank or null?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am using `g:datePicker`, and in default selection in database inserting null, but I want to insert '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

```
<g:datePicker name="doseOneDue" precision="day"  noSelection="['':'-Choose-']"  value="${immunizationInstance?.doseOneDue}" relativeYears="[-2..5]" default="none"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I never tried this (and do not have a grails environment at work today) but you could try something like

```
class myDomain {
  Date aDateField

static constraintes = {
    aDateField blank: false, defaultValue: Calendar.set(0,0,0,0,0)
}
```

I also do not know if it would work as date starts from 1970 for computers.